# WP CLI Shell not working on Windows

Tags: windows, wordpress, command-line-interface

I recently installed WP-CLI on windows with the instructions below. However when I type wp shell I get an error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

One solution on github says:

> Psysh is not bundled in wp-cli.phar, but you should be able to include
>   it, like so:
>
> wget psysh.org/psysh -O psysh.phar php wp-cli.phar
>   --require=psysh.phar shell

however, that also produces an error:

> 'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Please help! I'm too far down the rabbit hole. I wanted to use WP CLI to make my life easier!

Installation instructions followed (from http://wp-cli.org/docs/installing/):

> Installing on Windows# Install via composer as described above or use the following method.
>
> Make sure you have php installed and in your path so you can execute
>   it globally.
>
> Download wp-cli.phar manually and save it to a folder, for example
>   c:\wp-cli
>
> Create a file named wp.bat in c:\wp-cli with the following contents:
>
> `@ECHO OFF php "c:/wp-cli/wp-cli.phar" %*`
>
> Add c:\wp-cli to your path:
>
> `setx path "%path%;c:\wp-cli"`
>
> You can now use WP-CLI from anywhere in
>   Windows command line

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing the instructions for installing WP-CLI via Composer with the instructions for installing manually. You need to stick with one or the other. I remember following the manual installation instructions and everything went fine. Follow just those instructions. Forget about Composer for now.

`wget` is a Unix program and does not work on Windows without specifically installing it. Don't use it for this installation.

It sounds like either `WP-CLI` or `PHP` is missing from your global path. Follow the instructions at http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath to ensure PHP is executable globally. Specifically the following:

> Go to Control Panel and open the System icon (Start → Control Panel)
>
> Go to the Advanced tab
>
> Click on the 'Environment Variables' button
>
> Look into the 'System Variables' pane
>
> Find the Path entry (you may need to scroll to find it)
>
> Double click on the Path entry
>
> Enter your PHP directory at the end, including ';' before (e.g.
>   ;C:\php)
>
> Press OK

Do the same for the path to the `WP-CLI` executable. Result should look somewhat like my own PATH below.

[image: windows path]

Comment: To clarify, everything about WP CLI is working fine, except the command `wp shell`, which apparently relies on something called psysh.

Comment: @Robin My apologies I misread. After reading your comment, I tried `wp shell` and got the same error you got. You're definitely onto something. I suggest editing your question to mention that other CLI commands are working fine.

Comment: I wasn't able to get WP-CLI working until I read these instructions. I was getting an error that said "wp" was not an internal command in Windows. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

The `wp shell` command requires a library called `psysh` to work properly on Windows. While there are suggestions out there to get it work by installing the psysh library globally (also mentioned in the question), I didn't like the idea of having to install a global dependency to composer for just one library. While this worked fine, it felt a little too much like an anti-pattern to me.

Instead I [forked wp-cli-bundle](https://github.com/lipemat/wp-cli-bundle) to create a version of `wp-cli.phar` which has `psysh` built in so `wp shell` will work on Windows. 
This fork also has a few other Windows related enhancements. See the [Readme.md](https://github.com/lipemat/wp-cli-bundle/blob/master/README.md#this-version-was-forked-to-keep-it-compatible-with-windows-for-things-like-wp-shell) for the current list.

You may download that [latest wp-cli.phar here](https://github.com/lipemat/wp-cli-bundle/releases/latest/download/wp-cli.phar) or previous versions from the [Releases section](https://github.com/lipemat/wp-cli-bundle/releases/).

[image]

Comment: Really this answer should be getting a lot of points! Thanks so much @Mat Lipe it works! Also can you tell us what you did on your forked repo as far as customizations to get psysh working in windows? I ran the composer install and just used the vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/bin/wp as my wp-cli and it works great.

Comment: Thank you for alerting to this answer which was in need of a refresh as the structure of wp-cli and therefore the repos changed quite a while back. The answer has been updated to reflect the new locations. To answer your question: Basically I bundled the `Psysh` library inside the generated `wp-cli.phar` to make it work on Windows.

Comment: Here is the commit which included the changed I made to add `Psysh` to the bundle. https://github.com/lipemat/wp-cli-bundle/commit/0b75d5de26337ae6176434fc976979f730a33c36